Firebase on Firefox, modules not supported
I have some Firebase code for push notifications that is working on Chrome and iOS Safari, but I can't get it working with Firefox
The documentation says that modules are not supported on Firefox
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker#browser_compatibility
And Firebase says that at some point it'll drop support for non module versions
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade
"the compat libraries are a temporary solution that will be removed completely in a future major SDK version"
Also, when I try this
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.13.1/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.13.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.13.1/firebase-messaging-sw-compat.js');

The last script doesn't have a compat version?
So I'm not sure if I should even be using the compat versions, but I can't get them working anyway?
